# why is echo changing font size on the rest of my page?

Tags: php, dialog, echo

I'm getting angry at this, i'm setting up a jquery dialog box, heres the code i'm using to echo it:

```
echo "
<div class='dialog' title='Edit Record'>
    <form method='post'>    
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type='text' value='$row[name]' name='name'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cash Down</td>
                <td><input type='text' value='$row[cash]' name='cash'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Amount</td>
                <td><input type='text' value='$row[amount]' name='amount'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mem Type</td>
                <td><input type='text' value='$row[type]' name='type'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Code</td>
                <td><input type='text' value='$row[code]' name='code'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Month</td>
                <td><input type='text' value='$row[m]' name='m'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Instructor</td>
                <td><input type='text' value='$row[instructor]' name='instructor'></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type='submit' value='Edit' name='Editrenewal'>
    </form>
</div>";
```

heres what my page looks like before i open the echo'd dialog:

[image: before]

and then when i click the link that triggers the dialog it turns into this:

[image: GRRR]

you can clearly see how much bigger and uglier everything gets

Comment: It's related to css..echo doesn't effect the style..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you echo-ing that div inside the body?

Comment: derp. was above the body. figures it was something this obvious